# window object not available on $scope in controller / link functions

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-kendo, kendo-window

I placed a `kendo-window` in my html.

according to the [docs](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/angular), the window object should be available on the scope.

now, I want to bind a listener to the window's `activate` event from within a controller that is declared inside the window.   i.e.:

markup:

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <div kendo-window='potatoWindow'>
        <div ng-controller='PotatoController'>
            here
        </div>
    </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "kendo.directives"]);

app.controller("PotatoController", function($scope){
    $scope.potatoWindow.bind("activate",
        function () {
            console.log("potato");
        });
});
```

... but the window object (`potatoWindow`) is not found on the `$scope` during the controller.

Qs:

1. why is the window object not available? am i missing something?
2. if there is no way to access the window object - is there a way to get the same results by other means?

Answer (score 2):

I think your kendo-window markup needs to be part of the controller markup.
Also, try using the `k-on-activate` binding and define your function in the controller like this:

MARKUP:

```
  <div ng-controller='PotatoController'>
             <div kendo-window='potatoWindow' k-on-activate='fry()'>
                 here
             </div>
   </div>
```

JS:

```
  var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "kendo.directives"]);    
    app.controller("PotatoController", function($scope){
         $scope.fry = function(e){
              console.log('fried!');
         };
    });
```